# How to minifiy angular code for production?

Tags: angularjs

My project is going to production that is developed by using Node and angular , How i can  minifiy angular code in production.

I want Following controller minifiy or uglify .if i minifiy the code in online then application is not working.

```
    var sidemenu = angular.module('sidemenuApp', ['ngMaterial', 'ngAria', 'ngAnimate',
        'slickCarousel', 'ngCookies', 'ui.bootstrap', 'headroom', 'ngRoute','duScroll','infinite-scroll','angular-spinkit']);

    sidemenu.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
        $routeProvider
            .when('/builders/:id', {  
                templateUrl: '../template/listpagefilter.html',
                controller: 'buildersCtrl'
            })

             .when('/builders/:id/property/:property_id',{ 
                      templateUrl: '../view/property-details.html',
                      controller: 'unitTypeCtrl'  
            })     

           .when('/property/:property_id',{
                      templateUrl: '../view/property-details.html',
                      controller: 'unitTypeCtrl'  
            }) 

              .when('/location/:city_name/:location_id',{ 
                templateUrl: '../template/listpagefilter.html',
                controller: 'buildersCtrl'
            })



        }])

here is mu controller , i need to minify and uglify the code.


     sidemenu.controller('buildersCtrl', ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$location', '$http', 'allServices','$document',
                         'PropertyDetails','$routeParams','$window','$uibModal','$mdDialog',
                         'customVariables',function (a, b, c, d, e,f,h,r,w,u,v,cust) {

                b.contactwdgt = "";
                b.header = true;
                b.homepage = false;
                b.filter = true;
                b.innerHeader = "inner-page-hdr";
                a.composite = false;

                a.$on('$routeChangeStart', function(scope, next, current) {
                    b.homepage = true;
                    b.filter = false;
                    b.innerHeader = "";
                    b.searchFilter = false;
                    b.contactwdgt = "contact-wdgt";
                    srchCls_Element.removeClass('listing-navbar');

                });


            a.hmpProperies = function(properties) {

                    if (properties.length < 3) {
                        a.composite = true;
                    }
                  }


                e.projectListing(r,paging).then(function(result) {


                    a.properties = result.data.items;

                    if(result.data.items.length<=3){
                         a.showStructure = false;
                    }


                }, function(error) {

                });
                a.showStructure = false;
                var Execution = true;
                a.loadMoreRecords = function() {
                    a.showStructure = false;
                    var offset = paging.start + paging.rows;
                    paging = {
                        start: offset,
                        rows: 3
                    };


        a.getRaiseQuery=function(propertyId){
                  b.propid=propertyId
                 v.show({
                    templateUrl: 'view/raisequiry.html',
                    controller: DialogController,
                    clickOutsideToClose:true,
                    fullscreen: a.customFullscreen // Only for -xs, -sm breakpoints.
                })

        }  

        }]);
```

Comment: Use grunt, would very simple.

Comment: you can use uglifyjs.

Comment: can i have document to follow steps ?

Comment: https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS

Answer (score 1):

Angular js 1.x code isn't straight forward minifiable unless you have followed a proper pattern something like below, so that uglify doesn't minify injected services like $scope, $http, MyCustomService to a,b and c.

```
var NewCtrler = ['$scope', '$http','MyCustomService', function($scope, $http, MyCustomService) {
  $http.get(MyCustomService.restfulUrl)
    .success(function(data) {
      $scope.recievedData = data;
      MyCustomService.doSomething();
    })
}]
```

please use this [link](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_05#a-note-on-minification) for directions on minification from a angularjs website

once your code is ready you can use [uglify](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-uglify) to minify your code with grunt/gulp.

Read more on angular dependency injection and strict-di to get fair understanding how [dependency injection](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di) works and how [strict-di](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/strictdi) helps with minified code.